# Object must implement IConvertible When inserting bytes into VARBINARY field

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I have seen a lot people with this problem on the web, and I have yet to find a solution that solves my problem.

I have this code here:

```
byte[] bytes = btnBrowse.FileBytes;
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["shbndbConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert Into tblProject (id,updateDate,statusUpdate,attachment) Values (@projectId,GETDATE(),@statusUpdate,@file)", conn);

cmd.Parameters.Add("@file",SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = bytes;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@statusUpdate",SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtStatusUpdate;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@projectId",SqlDbType.Int).Value = lblProjectId.Text;

//cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
conn.Open();

if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() >= 1)
{
   lblDone.Text = "Success";
   lblDone.Visible = true;
}

conn.Close();
```

Now I keep getting this error:

> Object must implement IConvertible.

From what I understood it is because I am trying to insert an array into the table, but every website I go to says that the way I inserted it is correct.

Why am I receiving this error?

The `VARBINARY` column length in my table is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cause of the exception is most likely this line, where you're attempting to assign the entire TextBox as the parameter value:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@statusUpdate",SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtStatusUpdate;
```

Use `txtStatusUpdate.Text` to get the actual value from the TextBox.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@statusUpdate",SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtStatusUpdate.Text;
```